# Adding jpg images together using java

Tags: java, image, graphics, compilation, bufferedimage

I am trying to take severial jpg images with the same dimensions(30*30) and create a single image. Like this:

```
Image i = new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) i.getGraphics();
    if (this instanceof Node) {
        Image img;
        img = getImageFromFile(Node.icon);
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
    if(this instanceof ForceNode){
        Image img;
        img = getImageFromFile(ForceNode.forceicon);
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
    if(this instanceof TunnelNode){
        Image img;
        img = getImageFromFile(TunnelNode.tunnelicon);
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
....

public Image getImageFromFile(File file) {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(HackerGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        return null;
    }
    return image;


}
```

I realize there are some issues with G2D not being strictly necessary, but my issue is this:
These images needs to be put on top of each other to create a whole image. Eash of the images are small areas of the whole picture, that needs to be put on top of(Not next to) each other to create the actual image.  The problem right now however is that the last drawImage method overwrites the entire image, so i am left with the last "bit of image" instead of my compiled image.

I suspect this is because the white areas of my pictures are not being treated as transparent, but how do i get around this. I have next to no experience with image encoding so i am sort of going by trial and error:)
Anyway HELP!

Solution:

```
public void generateIcon() {
    BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    if (this instanceof Node) {
        i = compileImages(i, Node.icon);
    }
    if(this instanceof ForceNode){
        i = compileImages(i, ForceNode.forceicon);
    }
    if(this instanceof TunnelNode){
        i = compileImages(i, TunnelNode.tunnelicon);
    }
    if (this instanceof EntranceNode) {
        i = compileImages(i, EntranceNode.entranceicon);
    }
    if (this instanceof NetworkNode) {
        i = compileImages(i, NetworkNode.networkicon);
    }
    if(this instanceof DataNode){
        i = compileImages(i, DataNode.dataicon);
    }

    //if(this instanceof )


    nodeicon = i;
}

public BufferedImage compileImages(BufferedImage image, File f) {
    BufferedImage im = null;
    try {
        im = ImageIO.read(f);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<image.getWidth();i++){
            for(int j = 0 ; j<image.getHeight();j++){
                int rgb = im.getRGB(i, j);
                //System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + rgb);
                if(!(rgb < 1 && rgb > -2)){
                    image.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
                    //System.out.println("Printing " + i + " " + j + " " + rgb);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(HackerGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        return null;
    }
    return image;


}
```

Comment: Your suspicion is correct.  Are the images JPG's or PGN's? Can you get transparent images to start with?

Comment: As far as I know, the JPG format does not support transparency. So if you load a JPG file, then Java cannot know which pixels of the image should be treated as transparent - that information is simply not in the JPG file. PNG does support transparency - can you save your source images as PNG?

Comment: @Jesper  JPEG *does* support transparency, though I've never encountered one, and can't say if Java supports transparent JPEGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the pixels of the source images.  If they are *not* white (use `getRGB(x,y)`to compare them), write them to the destination image.

Comment: Thank you. That worked very well. I expect that -1 from getRGB(x,y) is white? Or is 0 also white, or transparent?

Comment: (whispers)  I never bother to check.  I just instantiate the target color(s), & call `getRGB()` on the instance(s).  It gets around all possible presumptions about how Java chooses to store/represent it.  ;)